# How to load my product details page module for specific category in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, layout

I have installed a custom module with the code of Finance calculator, going to display in product details/view page. Now, i want to display/load the plug-in in product details page for specific category, for example some of the category products need finance calculator and some category products do not require.

For some performance issues i can not add `php if module enable` condition in .phtml or template.

Can any one suggest me,

1. Is their any possibility to add a category specific condition from layout - catalog_product_view.xml.
2. Is there any other possibility to achieve this ?

Comment: I think create another Layout & Manage it with Category -> Design Options

Comment: I can not update by going individual category, am looking for something from layout, events or block.

Comment: So i think u need to check in Observer first (which Category) & on basis of that you have to display that block on product detail page https://amasty.com/customer-group-catalog-for-magento-2.html

Comment: why not just register some config value with observer and then use `ifconfig` is layout ?